# How to replace the div by clicking an arrow using js?

Tags: javascript, css, project

While clicking the arrow the new div should replace. How can I code for it in js

I don't know how to do it using js.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice for you to include what code you have so far to help us help you. However, assuming you have some basic JavaScript you can use

```
document.getElementById("Arrow").addEventListener("click", function(){
   const div1 = document.getElementByID("div1");
   div1.style.display = 'none';  //Hides Div1

   const div2 = document.getElementByID("div2");
   div2.style.display = 'block'; //Shows Div2, 'block' can be any display
});
```

Alternatively you could use

```
document.getElementById("Arrow").addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("Div1").innerHTML = NewText;
});
```

This rewrites the html of the div to the new stuff that you want.